# What structure is the best for "Get first X elements with best priority"?

Tags: java, performance, collections

I have a lot of elements with int priority. Priority of the element is changable.

Count of operations `getFirstPriorityElements(int count)` - n
Count of operations `updatePriorityOfElement(Object o, int priority)` - n

What is best performance structure should I use to get first X elements with best priority?

Comment: When you get elements, do you expect them to be removed from the structure?

Comment: no, I dont need them to be removed

Comment: Whoever down-voted, please explain why.

Comment: Does updating an element's priority always increase it?

Comment: No, priority are changed randomly

Answer (score 1):

A `PriorityQueue` or a `TreeSet` would suit you if you wanted to have a constant priority (the queue is if you want to pop elements, the set - if you want to keep them).

However, with changing priority, you have to reorder the collection on each change. Or better - before each iteration. That should be synchronous, though.

So, make a collection that uses a custom `Comparator`, and on each invocation of `iterator()` reorderes its elements. For example you can extend `TreeSet` and override the `iterator()` method. Then you call `next()` `n` times.